# Error upgrading Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04 : Error authenticating some pakages

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 15.04

I tried to upgrade ubuntu from 14 to 15.
[image]

A window pops up and interrupt the upgrade process.
[image: screenshot]

The error is in `Setting new software channels`[image]

Can anyone help please?

**Note: I have no internet problem**

[image]

Comment: You should not upgrade from 14.04 to 15.04, this is probably a bug in the update manager since you can not skip releases.

Comment: If it is really a bug, it should be closed here and you should write a bug report on launchpad instead. However if there's a workaround or quick fix one can manually apply, then that should be posted as answer and the question should stay open.