# I am recommended to upgrade from 14.04 to 15.04 but it fails

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 15.04, do-release-upgrade

Every time I reboot my fully updated laptop running **Ubuntu 14.04 amd64**  I am greeted with this dialogue window at login:

[image: Ubuntu 15.04 Upgrade Available Dialogue Window]

When I press the "Yes, Upgrade Now" button I see this very promising dialogue:

[image: Release Notes: Welcome to Ubuntu 15.04 'Vivid Vervet']

**EDIT: This is not a promising dialogue after all! The suggested upgrade path 14.04 -> 15.04 is not possible. Instead it should suggest 14.10 or next LTS. Please see the bug that I posted about this [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1537943).**

But when I press the "Upgrade" button and type in my password I see this:

[image: Failed to fetch: Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem.]

I can with 100% confidence say that there is no network problem (I am listening to an internet radio station while writing this in my browser).

So I decided to see if I could coax out some more meaningful error messages by running the upgrade again using commandline. I open a terminal and run the command `sudo do-release-upgrade`. I get the following log:

```
lennart@katana:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade 
[sudo] password for lennart: 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Err Upgrade tool signature                                                     
  403  Sorry, not allowed to fetch that type of file: vivid.tar.gz.gpg         
Err Upgrade tool                                                               
  403  Sorry, not allowed to fetch that type of file: vivid.tar.gz             
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      
WARNING:root:file 'vivid.tar.gz.gpg' missing
Failed to fetch
Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem. 
lennart@katana:~$
```

So now I am stumped. Is there no way for me to perform this upgrade? Where should I look for ways to proceed or troubleshoot this? I am quite fond of my current install, it is set up perfectly, and it is fairly cruft free. I really would like to preserve it if possible.

Any tips welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't do this. You can not skip releases but somehow the update manager is suggesting it. I've seen issues like this since December 30. I recomendo to select "Don't upgrade".

Comment: You can see here a duplicate of your problem (that ended up wrong because of the release skip) http://askubuntu.com/questions/724635/error-upgrading-ubuntu-14-04-to-15-04-error-authenticating-some-pakages for whatever reason, the update manager is suggesting a Wrong upgrade path.

Comment: How can i tell my system to try 14.10 first?

Comment: Please notice that Ubuntu 14.04 is still supported and will be for another three more years. If you choose to upgrade you will have to upgrade one by one and gradually from Ubuntu 14.04 to 14.10, 15.04 and 15.10 finally. So do you really need to upgrade? I repeat one more time that for whatever reason the update manager is suggesting a Wrong update path, it should have to in first place.

Comment: I really want to syay closer to the edge. If 14.04 is supported then there may be hope that the bugreport I just submitted will be fixed and I can move on before my 3 years are up!

Comment: May I know the bug report number?

Comment: Of course! https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1537943

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my **apt-cacher** install was getting in the way.

I simply removed my `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy`, then proceeded to run

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and finally when running

```
do-release-upgrade
```

it stopped whining about this:

> 403  Sorry, not allowed to fetch that type of file: vivid.tar.gz.gpg

NOTE: your proxy settings might be different than mine. Look for the file inside `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` that contains the string proxy.